# How to call a action in other controller

Tags: java, playframework

I'm working on a play framework project, and I'm wondering whether there is any way to call an action from other controller. Redirecting is not the solution because these are 2 pages with different url (but the logic action is the same).

Anyone got a clue. So pleased if you can give me a hint to do this

Thanks

Comment: Didn't get the point of not using `return redirect("\url");`
Why don't you call the corresponding method directly, as we call any other function.?

Answer (score 1):

If they are 2 different actions in 2 different pages and you want to chain them, redirection is the standard way. If you can't because that would move the user out of an area of the application, then you may need to reconsider if your design is right. Maybe you shouldn't have only 2, but a 3rd page, or something else.

If they are 2 pages with common code, then create a 3rd class with the common code and call as required.